# how can make different conditions in one collection in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

here is my one new function i have minify it need to make a single use of collection for delay and verify, how to make common filter for all.

$collection and $citycollection also need to make one, how to do please help .

my function is :

```
$cust_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $arr = $college = $campus = array();    
        array_push($arr, $cust_id);
        print_r($cust_id);
        $collection = Mage::getModel("manager/campus")->getCollection()
                                                        ->addFieldToFilter('regionalmanager',array('finset' => $arr))
                                                        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));

        $count = $collection->count();
        $citycollection =  Mage::getModel("manager/campus")->getCollection()
                                                            ->addFieldToFilter('citymanager', array('eq' => $cust_id))
                                                            ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));

        if ($collection->count() > 0)
        { 
            $allcollege = array();
            $flag = 0;
            foreach ($collection as $collegename)
            {
                array_push($college, $collegename->getId());
            }
            if ($verifystatus == 'delay')
            {
                $delayedcollection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' =>$college))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4, 5)))
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('assigned_campus_manager', array('null' => true), 'left')
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('physical_verify', array('null' => true), 'left')
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('grisk_pv_upload_date', array('lt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($configValue))))
                                    ->addAttributeToSort('grisk_pv_upload_date', 'DESC')
                                    ->setPage(1, 50);
                $flag = 1;
            }
            elseif ($verifystatus == 'verify')
            {
                $delayedcollection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' => $college))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4, 5)))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('grisk_pv_upload_date',array('lt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($configValue))))
                                    ->addAttributeToSort('grisk_pv_upload_date', 'DESC')
                                    ->setPage(1, 50);
                $flag = 1;
            }
            ************** 

         else if ($citycollection->count() > 0)
            {
                $flag = 0;
                foreach ($citycollection as $collegename)
                {
                    array_push($college, $collegename->getId());
                }
                if ($verifystatus == 'delay') {
                    $delayedcollection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
                                                                            ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
                                                                            ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' => $college))
                                                                            ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4, 5)))
                                                                            ->addFieldToFilter('grisk_pv_upload_date', array('lt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($configValue))))
                                                                            ->addAttributeToSort('grisk_pv_upload_date', 'DESC')
                                                                            ->setPage(1, 50);
                    $flag = 1;
                }
                elseif($verifystatus == 'verify')
                {
                    $delayedcollection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
                                                                            ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
                                                                            ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' =>  $college))
                                                                            ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', 6)
                                                                            ->addFieldToFilter('grisk_pv_upload_date',array('lt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($configValue))))
                                                                            ->addAttributeToSort('grisk_pv_upload_date', 'DESC')
                                                                            ->setPage(1, 50);
                    $flag = 1;
                }
```

my try for solution is :

```
array_push($arr, $cust_id);
        $collection = Mage::getModel("manager/campus")->getCollection();
        if($regionalmanager) {
            $collection->getSelect()->addFieldToFilter('regionalmanager',array('finset' => $arr));
        } else {
            $collection->getSelect()->addFieldToFilter('citymanager', array('eq' => $cust_id));
        }
            $collection->getSelect()->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));

        if ($collection->count() > 0)
        { 
            $allcollege = array();
            $flag = 0;
            foreach ($collection as $collegename)
            {
                array_push($college, $collegename->getId());
            }
                $delayedcollection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
                                                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                                        ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' =>$college))
                                                                        ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4, 5)))
                                                                        ->addFieldToFilter('grisk_pv_upload_date', array('lt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($configValue))))         
                                                                        ->addAttributeToSort('grisk_pv_upload_date', 'DESC')
                                                                        ->setPage(1, 50);

            if ($verifystatus == 'delay')
            {
                $delayedcollection  = $delayedcollection->getSelect()
                                                        ->addAttributeToFilter('assigned_campus_manager', array('null' => true), 'left')
                                                        ->addAttributeToFilter('physical_verify', array('null' => true), 'left');


            }else if($verifystatus == 'verify')
            {    $delayedcollection =$delayedcollection->


                $flag = 1;
            }
  }
        else if ($citycollection->count() > 0)
            {
                $flag = 0;
                foreach ($citycollection as $collegename)
                {
                    array_push($college, $collegename->getId());
                }
                if ($verifystatus == 'delay') {
                    $delayedcollection = $delayedcollection->getSelect()->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
                                                                        ->setPage(1, 50);
                    $flag = 1;
                }
                elseif($verifystatus == 'verify')
                {
                    $delayedcollection = $delayedcollection = $delayedcollection->getSelect()
                                                                            ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
                                                                            ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', 6)
                                                                            ->setPage(1, 50);
                    $flag = 1;
                } 
                if($flag)
                {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate function which returns the collection based on the parameters.

```
private function getCustomerCollection($attributeToSelect, $college, $groups, $configValue, $delayedStatus = false)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributeToSelect);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' =>  $college));
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $groups);

    if ($delayedStatus == true)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('assigned_campus_manager', array('null' => true), 'left');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('physical_verify', array('null' => true), 'left');
    }

    $collection->addFieldToFilter('grisk_pv_upload_date',array('lt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($configValue))));
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('grisk_pv_upload_date', 'DESC');
    $collection->setPage(1, 50);

    return $collection;
}
```

And you can call this function to get the collection with respective parameters. In your case,

```
if ($collection->count() > 0)
{ 
    $allcollege = array();
    $flag = 0;
    foreach ($collection as $collegename)
    {
        array_push($college, $collegename->getId());
    }
    if ($verifystatus == 'delay')
    {
        $delayedcollection = $this->getCustomerCollection('*', $college, array(4, 5), $configValue, true);
        $flag = 1;
    }
    elseif ($verifystatus == 'verify')
    {
        $delayedcollection = $this->getCustomerCollection('*', $college, array(4, 5), $configValue);
        $flag = 1;
    }
************** 

else if ($citycollection->count() > 0)
{
    $flag = 0;
foreach ($citycollection as $collegename)
{
    array_push($college, $collegename->getId());
}
if ($verifystatus == 'delay') {
    $delayedcollection = $this->getCustomerCollection('firstname', $college, array(4, 5), $configValue);
    $flag = 1;
}
elseif($verifystatus == 'verify')
{
    $delayedcollection = $this->getCustomerCollection('firstname', $college, array('6'), $configValue);
    $flag = 1;
}
```

For $collection and $citycollection you can create a similar function like above, pass the respective parameters and also pass(if needed) a additional parameter to identify whether it is a collection or city collection.

Hope it helps!

Comment: instead of function can u please help me out in making common collection

Comment: updated my try please check ..

Comment: is your try works?

Comment: i want in this way, no another   function ,  but no idea how to make it done properly

Comment: You can try joining the tables customer/customer and manager/campus, which helps in retrieve the results with better performance than now