# how to merge two collection in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, model

```
  $collection = Mage::getModel("manager/campus")->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('regionalmanager',array('finset' => $arr))
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
    /* GET citymanager collection */
    $citycollection  =  Mage::getModel("manager/campus")->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('citymanager', array('eq' => $cust_id))
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));`enter code here`
```

Comment: Can you provide more details how you want to merge? with example output of both collection and the final output which you want to achieve.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434996/magento-how-to-merge-two-product-collections-into-one) and [this](http://tech-jeff.com/blog/magento-how-to-merge-two-product-collections-into-one?tag=Magento)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("manager/campus")->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter( 
        array('regionalmanager','citymanager'), 
        array( array('finset'=>$arr),array('eq'=>$cust_id))
        )
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
```

Comment: can u please help me out for this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170516/how-can-make-different-conditions-in-one-collection-in-magento-1-9/170525?noredirect=1#comment234132_170525

Comment: is your above query is solved? @supriyamishra

Comment: Yes @gopal-patel

Comment: then mark it as accepted to close the question @supriyamishra

Answer (score 1):

try this. But this is not best pratics

> ```
>  $merged_ids = array_merge($collection->getAllIds(), $citycollection->getAllIds());
> $finalCollection =  Mage::getModel("manager/campus")->getCollection()
>         ->addFieldToFilter('[TablePrimarykey]', array('in' => $merged_ids));
> ```

Comment: can u please help me out for this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170516/how-can-make-different-conditions-in-one-collection-in-magento-1-9/170525?noredirect=1#comment234132_170525